# Writing Basis for the unit cell

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

I'm following *The oxford solid state basics* By S. Simon. I'm sort of confused, How he has written the basis in different places?

The definition that is given goes like this:

> *The description of objects in the unit cell with respect to the reference lattice point in the unit cell known as a **basis**.*

He has given the following example:

[image]

Basis  for  crystal

Large Light Gray Atom  have Position : $[a/2,a/2]$

Large Light Gray Atom have Position  $[a/4,a/4]$, $[a/4,3a/4]$ , $[3a/4,a/4]$ and  $[3a/4,3a/4]$.
I have no problem with this.

The reference points (the small black dots in figure) forming the square lattice have positions
$$\mathbf{R}_{[n_1,n_2]}=[an_1,an_2]=an_1\hat{x}+an_2\hat{y}$$
so that the large light gray atoms have positions
$$\mathbf{R}^\mathbf{light-gray}_{[n_1,n_2]}=[an_1,an_2]+[a/2,a/2]$$
whereas the small dark gray atoms have positions

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{dark-gray^1}_{[n_1,n_2]} &= [an_1,an_2]+[a/4,a/4]  \\
    \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{dark-gray^2}_{[n_1,n_2]} &= [an_1,an_2]+[a/4,3a/4]  \\
  \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{dark-gray^3}_{[n_1,n_2]} &= [an_1,an_2]+[3a/4,a/4]  \\
  \mathbf{R}^\mathbf{dark-gray^4}_{[n_1,n_2]} &= [an_1,an_2]+[3a/4,3a/4] 
  \end{align*}
And I have no problem till this.

---

For the BCC structure, he has written the basis to be $[0,0,0]$ and $[1/2,1/2,1/2]$. By which one can write,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{R}_\mathrm{corner} &= [n_1,n_2,n_3] \\
   \mathbf{R}_\text{center} &= [n_1,n_2,n_3] + \left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]
\end{align*}

The sodium has a BCC structure and thus it should follow this. But in his examples, he has written that the basis $=$ Na at $[0,0,0]$. *I do not understand, How he did that?*

Further for the diamond which has an fcc structure, He has given basis to be C at $[0,0,0]$ and C at $[1/4,1/4,1/4]$ and a similar problem is with Cu, again an fcc, he has given basis to be Cu at $[0,0,0]$? I don't understand these examples.

Can anybody make me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the reason for the confusion is due to the possibility of describing highly symmetric [crystal structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure) in an alternative way using different [Bravais lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice) of symmetry translations. Depending on the choice of the underlying Bravais lattice, a bcc or a diamond lattice may be described with different Bravais lattices, then different unit cells, and consequently, different atomic bases.

In the case of the bcc lattice, it can be described as $1)$ a crystal structure characterized by a bcc Bravais lattice with a non-cubic [primitive cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_cell), therefore a one-atom basis, or $2)$ as a simple cubic Bravais lattice with a cubic unit cell containing a two-atom basis.

In the former case, a possible choice of the basis vectors of the bcc-Bravais lattice is (using an orthogonal set of unit vectors)
$$
\begin{align}
{\bf a}_1&=\frac{a}{2}(-{\bf \hat x}+{\bf \hat y}+{\bf \hat z})\\
{\bf a}_2&=\frac{a}{2}( {\bf \hat x}-{\bf \hat y}+{\bf \hat z})\\
{\bf a}_3&=\frac{a}{2}( {\bf \hat x}+{\bf \hat y}-{\bf \hat z}),
\end{align}
$$
the Bravais lattice is described by
$$
{\bf R}_{n_1,n_2n_3}=n_1{\bf a}_1+n_2{\bf a}_2+n_3{\bf a}_3,\tag{1}
$$
with $n_i \in {\mathbb Z}$, and a possible basis has one atom at $(0,0,0)$.

In the latter case, the simple cubic base can be described as
$$
\begin{align}
{\bf a'}_1&=a{\bf \hat x}\\
{\bf a'}_2&=a{\bf \hat y}\\
{\bf a'}_3&=a{\bf \hat z}
\end{align}
$$
the Bravais lattice as in equation $(1)$ with ${\bf a'}_i$ in place of the ${\bf a}_i$, and a possible two-atom basis with atoms in
$(0,0,0)$ and $a\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12\right)$.

The case of the diamond lattice is analogous. It can be described as an fcc Bravais lattice with a two-atom basis, for instance at $(0,0,0)$ and $a\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14\right)$. Alternatively, it can be described as a simple cubic Bravais lattice with an eight-atom unit cell.

Comment: Yes, the ambiguity arises as Simon doesn't describe the non-cubic unit cell (even though he mentions the existence of the alternatives). I have a question though, is it always possible to find a primitive cell enclosing 1 atom for any lattice made of single type of atom? For instance, is it possible to find non-cubic primitive cell for diamond such that we will need only 1 basis or single-atom basis?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand, no, it is not always possible to have always a one-atom basis even for one-component systems. The case of Silicon or Carbon are illustrations of such a point. It is evident that the vector joining the positions of the two atoms of the minimal basis does not represent a symmetry translation of the lattice. Therefore, using (at least) a two-atom basis is unavoidable.